# Insert con asp clasic en sql

Tags: sql, asp

Hola alguien me puede ayudar con el insert no me funciona no se donde puede estar el error porque no me lanza ninguno

```
SET cnn2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
cnn2.CommandTimeout = 90
cnn2.ConnectionTimeout =90
Server.ScriptTimeout = 90
cnn2.ConnectionString =cadenaconexion()

cnn2.open
consulta = " INSERT INTO [LINKNUEVOOK].[dbo].[USUARIOLINKFAVORITOS] (userID, nombre, url)  VALUES ( " & idUsuario & " , '" & favorito & "', '" & urlCompleta & "')"
cnn2.Execute consulta
cnn2.close
```

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes si que es un error si no te muestra ninguno? ¿has probado a poner algo mal adrede para saber si te ejecuta?

Comment: Lo ejecuto del servidor y me da este error 500 - Error interno del servidor.
Hay un problema con el recurso que busca y no se puede mostrar. pero si comento la linea de insert si funciona

Comment: Has probado a insertar los values a *pelo*? `VALUES (1,"Valor1","https://es.stackoverflow.com")`

Comment: Si lo he probado la consulta funciona porque la he probado en sql y va bien

Comment: desde donde lo ejecutas? prueba a ver si dejando solo USUARIOLINKFAVORITOS te funciona, eliminando los corchetes

Comment: Lo ejecuto directamente desde el servidor si ya lo he probado y sale el mismo error

Comment: Puedes trata de debugear y en la variable consulta ver como esta formando el string lo tomamos y lo pasamos a SQL si no falla entonces el error esta en otro lado y podemos empezar a ver opciones

Comment: Hola haciendo un Response.Write me sale esto INSERT INTO USUARIOLINKFAVORITOS(userID, nombre, url) VALUES( 3142, 'Madrid', 'wwww.google.es') y si ejecuto esto en sql si me lo inserta

Comment: Acabo de cambiar la configuración del IIS para que me muestre los errores detallados en vez de errores en pagina personalizada y resulta que me esta denegando el permiso para hacer un insert